# How to join 3 tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables :

1. Transaction (ID_Transcation)
2. Transaction Detail (ID_Transaction_Detail, ID_Transaction, ID_Services)
3. Services (ID_Services, Name)

I want to get only the name of the services, based on the `ID_Transaction` in the `Transaction` table.

The table and output that I want:

[image]

Code I tried:

```
Select se.Name 
from Transactions as td, Services as se 
where td.ID_Transaction = 'TRA1'
```

But the output is displaying all the name from service table

Comment: Update your question and show your current query attempt.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select c.name 
from Transaction as a
inner join Detail as b
on a.ID_Transaction = b.ID_Transaction
inner join Services as c
on b.id_services = c.id_services;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query:

```
select * 
from Transaction,Detail,Services 
where Transaction.ID_Transcation=Detail.ID_Transaction 
    and Services.ID_Services=Detail.ID_Services;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Join condition and Table Join .

**Non ANSI:**

```
SELECT se.NAME
FROM Transactions AS td
    ,Transaction_Detail det
    ,Services AS se
WHERE 
td.ID_Transaction = det.ID_Transaction
AND det. ID_Services=  se. ID_Services
AND td.ID_Transaction = 'TRA1'
```

**ANSI:**

```
SELECT  se.NAME
FROM Transactions AS td
INNER JOIN Transaction_Detail AS det ON td.ID_Transaction = det.ID_Transaction
INNER JOIN Services  AS se ON det. ID_Services=  se. ID_Services
WHERE td.ID_Transaction = 'TRA1'
```

> ANSI standard Joins are preferred. They are readable and accepted over
>   multiple RDBMS.
>   If you use NON ANSI Join and if you forgot join condition then the result > will be`CROSS JOIN`